# Enviar los datos del intent Contactos, en onActivityResult a la .class que le corresponde

Tags: android-intent, onactivityresult

estoy ya mucho tiempo bloqueado en este punto y me impide continuar, necesito que el contacto o contactos seleccionados en tu agenda de contactos, se refleje en el metodo correspondiente. 
Con un onClick se activa un intent, el cual te lleva a contactos,

```
 case R.id.btn_agenda:

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONTACT);

                break;
```

en la misma clase necesito reflejar el contacto elegegido mediante, invocando un metodo. 
¿Como puedo reflejar el dato del intent para que se refleje en su recipiente loyaout de la App?

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = resultIntent.getData();
```

el metodo que pienso que ejecuta los datos y los refleja en un recipiente es:

```
@Override
    public void showRecipientsSelected(List<Recipient> recipients) {

        if (adapterRecipients == null) {
            adapterRecipients = new RecipientsAdapter(getActivity(), recipients);
            adapterRecipients.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            recyclerRecipients.setAdapter(adapterRecipients);

        } else {
            adapterRecipients.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        autocompleteRecipient.setText("");
    }
```

la App ya me refleja en este recipiente los contactos de una lista que sale de busqueda por texto, pero queria que fuera desde la agenda de contactos directamente. 
Posteriormente seria interesante poder seleccionar grupos o varios contactos y que se reflejaran todos en un click.

gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos del contacto, debes realizar una consulta a partir de la Uri, se genera un cursor y de este puedes obtener los datos del contacto.

Revisa este ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = resultIntent.getData();

            Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactUri, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

              String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
              String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              System.out.println("id: " + id + " Nombre: " + nombre);

                if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                   Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                   null, null);
                   phones.moveToFirst();
                   cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data_1"));
                   System.out.println("Numero télefonico : " + cNumber);
                }


            }


       }
   }
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, he podido completar el onActivityResult dándole un cursor para seleccionar el numero , Para que ese numero se vea en el recipiente donde van todos los contactos seleccionados. ¿debería cambiar,```System.out.println("Numero télefonico : " + cNumber);`` por el destino?